# Understanding more about categories for y axis in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Since just one-line information is available about categories in official website, I just wanted to one more information about it.

Considering this example:

```
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.categories
```

Is it that HighCharts on its own divides equally the scale into equal parts and names it as **1 , 2 ,3** etc if we dont specify the names for categories for both the axes?

If that is true what is the base for dividing the y axis into 7 equal parts in the above example fiddle  i.e., **0,50, ..250** why cant just two labels on y axis namely 0 and 250?

Comment: You didn't link to the jsfiddle that you are referencing.  You linked to the documentation

Comment: Those are ticks and you can modify them with several options like tickInterval, tickAmount, etc. I recommend to read more about it here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes